# Python speech recognition ubuntu ALSA lib

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, speech-recognition, pyaudio

I am trying to convert speech to text using SpeechRecognition on ubuntu 21.10

Here is the code

```
import speech_recognition as sr

def listen():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    mic = sr.Microphone(device_index=1)
    with mic as source:
        audio = r.listen(source, timeout=10)
        return r.recognize_google(audio)
print(listen())
```

This is throwing an error

```
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:877:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:877:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:877:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:877:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:377:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Unknown field port
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:377:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Unknown field port
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:486:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid type for card
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:486:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid type for card
Expression 'parameters->channelCount <= maxChans' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 1514
Expression 'ValidateParameters( inputParameters, hostApi, StreamDirection_In )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 2818
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/harsha/PycharmProjects/playground/audio.py", line 29, in <module>
    assitant.listen()
  File "/home/harsha/PycharmProjects/playground/audio.py", line 23, in listen
    with mic as source:
  File "/home/harsha/PycharmProjects/playground/sand/lib/python3.9/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 138, in __enter__
    self.audio.open(
  File "/home/harsha/PycharmProjects/playground/sand/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyaudio.py", line 750, in open
    stream = Stream(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/harsha/PycharmProjects/playground/sand/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyaudio.py", line 441, in __init__
    self._stream = pa.open(**arguments)
OSError: [Errno -9998] Invalid number of channels
```

I am doing this in my laptop with inbuilt microphone, I tried all possible answers on stack overflow please don't consider this as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because your device index is pointing to the wrong device.

Here's my suggestion:

Check the devices list:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

for mic in sr.Microphone.list_microphone_names():
    print(mic)
```

you will have a log like this:

```
HDA Intel PCH: ALC257 Analog (hw:0,0) // my mic with index 0
HDA Intel PCH: HDMI 0 (hw:0,3)
HDA Intel PCH: HDMI 1 (hw:0,7)
HDA Intel PCH: HDMI 2 (hw:0,8)
HDA Intel PCH: HDMI 3 (hw:0,9)
HDA Intel PCH: HDMI 4 (hw:0,10)
HDA NVidia: HDMI 0 (hw:1,3)
HDA NVidia: HDMI 1 (hw:1,7)
HDA NVidia: HDMI 2 (hw:1,8)
HDA NVidia: HDMI 3 (hw:1,9)
```

**But you can use the default mic by not setting a device index.**

```
import speech_recognition as sr

def listen():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    mic = sr.Microphone() // default device index
    with mic as source:
        // r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source) case you ever have noise issues
        audio = r.listen(source, timeout=10)
        return r.recognize_google(audio)
print(listen())
```

Comment: I tried checking the list of devices and got this sir ```ALSA lib pcm_route.c:877:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map```

Comment: If you are getting only `ALSA lib` without any error messages it means that you code its working. Those a only outputs from ALSA. Try to use the default mic by not setting a device_index. In case you are having trouble with `ALSA` check the `ALSA FILE: nano /usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf`. I would recommend you use a `print(say something)` just before `r.listen(source)`. If you code do have a error, plz let me know

Comment: the error is starting with ```ASLA lib  pcm_route.c:877:``` the program is crashing immediately its not listening  finally the error is ```OSError: [Errno -9998] Invalid number of channels```

Comment: Hello Thunder. which value are you using for device_index?